# how to resize an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

I have an array, which contains some elements. I hope to add some elements to the end of this array. Do you think that can I do for this? I don't want vector. how to resize and add the new element follow the last element?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `vector`? That's what it's there for.

Comment: If you only want to add elements, you can also use deque, stack, queue, list

Comment: Questions like "I want to do *<some really common thing>* but I don't want to use *<the standard library facility that exists to solve exactly that problem>*" are generally not very useful to future visitors and usually don't get answered. If you need a wheel and there is a high-quality steel wheel available to you for free, don't chisel a half-assed wheel out of stone instead. You don't do yourself any favors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Because of this, it does not make sense not to use vectors.

You have to use a dynamic array either from standard library like a `vector`  or through making it your self by using memory management facilities like `new` operator.

You can learn more about `vectors` [*here*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/).
You can learn more about `new` [*here*](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use upper limit of your input for array size .Then you used an extra variable for control . But i suggested to you for use vactor for get better result.